# Access State inside of mapDispatchToProps method

Tags: redux, react-redux

I have written a container component using redux and my implementation for `mapDispatchToProps` looks like this

```
const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch, ownProps) => {
    return {
        onChange: (newValue) => {
            dispatch(updateAttributeSelection('genre', newValue));
            dispatch(getTableData(newValue, ownProps.currentYear));
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is that in order to getTableData I need the state of some other components. How can I get access to the state object in this method?

Answer (score 63, accepted):

You can use redux-thunk to create a separate action creator function which has access to `getState`, rather than defining the function inside `mapDispatchToProps`:

```
function doTableActions(newValue, currentYear) {
    return (dispatch, getState) => {
        dispatch(updateAttributeSelection('genre', newValue));
        let state = getState();
        // do some logic based on state, and then:
        dispatch(getTableData(newValue, currentYear));
    }
}


let mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch, ownProps) => {
    return {
        onChange : (newValue) => {
            dispatch(doTableActions(newValue, ownProps.currentYear))
        }
    }
}
```

Some varying ways to go about organizing those, but something like that ought to work.

Comment: I think the real use case for accessing the state in mapDispatchToProps is to know which actions are available at runtime. For example you could map every possible action to a function and call it to dispatch the action or test it with an if clause to check whether the action is available.

Comment: From my point of view, so much complexity for doing such a simple things.

Answer (score 28):

Possible approach is also to use `mergeProps` that merges `mapState` and `mapDispatch` and allows to use both at the same time.

```
// Define mapState
const mapState = (state) => ({
  needeedValue: state.neededValue
})

// Define mapDispatch
const mapDispatch = (dispatch, ownProps) => {
  return {
    onChange: (newValue, neededValue) => {
      dispatch(updateAttributeSelection('genre', newValue));
      dispatch(getTableData(newValue, ownProps.currentYear, neededValue));
    }
  }
}

// Merge it all (create final props to be passed)
const mergeProps = (stateProps, dispatchProps, ownProps) => {
  return {
    ...stateProps,  // optional
    ...dispatchProps,  // optional
    onChangeWithNeededValue: (newValue) => (
      dispatchProps.onChange(
        newValue,
        stateProps.needeedValue  // <<< here the magic happens
      )
    )
  }
}

// Pass mergePros to connect
const MyContainer = connect(mapState, mapDispatch, mergeProps)(MyComponent);
```

Official documentation: [react-redux#connect](https://react-redux.js.org/api/connect)

Possible performance drawback on larger apps: [Stack Overflow - Performances and mergeProps in Redux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44641855/performances-and-mergeprops-in-redux)

Comment: This solution also passes `onChange` to `MyComponent`. You would have to exclude this prop in case you only want to pass down `onChangeWithNeededValue`.

Answer (score 7):

You can just use redux-thunk to get state.
Write a helper function like this:

```
const getState = (dispatch) => new Promise((resolve) => {
  dispatch((dispatch, getState) => {resolve(getState())})
})
```

You can use this in a async function or generator function:

```
const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch, ownProps) => {
  return {
    async someFunction() {
      const state = await getState(dispatch)
      ...
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use:

[redux-named-reducers](https://github.com/mileschristian/redux-named-reducers)

Which allows you to get state anywhere in your code like so:

```
const localState1 = getState(reducerA.state1)
const localState2 = getState(reducerB.state2)
```

Likewise in mapDispatchToProps:

```
const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
  return {
    onClick: () => {
      dispatch(someAction(getState(moduleA.state1)));
    }
  };
};
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have used Thunk Middleware then you can write helper function into your 
Action.Js

```
export const getSearchedText =  () => (dispatch, getState) => {
    const { app } = getState();
    return app.searchedText;
}
```

If you have been used the container design pattern, your property container should be below

Container.js

```
export const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch, ownProps) => {
    return {
             setSearch: search => {
                 var searchedText = dispatch(getSearchedText());
             }
}
```