# Redux connect optimize mergeProps

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I have a list of items that is rendered by the list like so:

```
items.map(item => (
  <ListItem
    item={item}
    updates={updates[item.id]}
    {/** other props like deleting loading*/}
  />
));
```

> Note that **item** here is not what is passed to the action creator
>   functions, ListItem is a container that will change this.

My item container has an [optimized mapStateToProps](https://react-redux.js.org/api/connect#factory-functions) (it returns a function, not an object):

```
const mapDispatchToProps = {
  updateItem,
  //others
}
const mapStateToProps = () => {
  //create momoized state creator
  const memoizedStateCreator = createMemoized();
  return (unused, { item, updates }) =>
    //use memoized state creator
    memoizedStateCreator(item, updates);
};
```

In the item when I click to save the item I have something like this:

```
<button onclick={updateItem(item)}
```

I would like to change this to

```
<button onclick={updateItem}
```

For that I can use [mergeProps](https://react-redux.js.org/api/connect#mergeprops-stateprops-dispatchprops-ownprops-object) but that would cause render of the Item (the Item function) to be called even though nothing changed because I always return a new reference as props. It would also cause react to do a shadow DOM compare of the result (instead of pure component that would skip that)

MergeProps cannot be optimized with a [factory function](https://react-redux.js.org/api/connect#factory-functions) (like mapStateToProps) where I can create a memoized function.

```
const mergeProps = (stateProps, dispatchProps) => ({
  ...stateProps,
  ...dispatchProps,
  updateItem: () => 
    stateProps.updateItem(stateProps.item),
});
```

One way to do this is to not use mergeProps at all and use a wrapper function instead:

```
const wrapper = props =>
  ListItem({
    ...props,
    updateItem: () => props.updateItem(props.item),
  });
export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  mapDispatchToProps
)(memo(wrapper));
```

My question is; is there a way to do this with mergeProps without having to turn my functional components into classes?

Returning a function from mapDispatchToProps would not work in my case because item does not come from ownProps, it comes from mapStateToProps

Comment: Is `requestDelete` a redux action? If so it probably should be mapped in `mapDispatchToProps`.

Comment: @trixn It is, first time `requestDelete` is in my question is in mapDispatchToProps object. But I see I use it wrong in mergeProps. Updated question.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that `requestDelete` is an action that can be dispatched you should map it in `mapDispatchToProps` of your connected `ListItem` component. `mapDispatchToProps` can also be a function that receives the `ownProps` as the second argument which has the `id`:

```
const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch, {item}}) => ({
    requestDelete: () => dispatch(requestDelete(item.id)),
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(ListItem);
```

Comment: That may be a nice solution, thank you. Did not see that [documented](https://react-redux.js.org/api/connect#factory-functions)

Comment: It would not work for me because item comes from mapStateToProps and ownProps passes item from List `<ListItem item={item}` that actually is a different item than what mapStateToProps gives me as that item can be merged with edits. Updating my question to make that clear.

Comment: @HMR But isn't the item identified by a unique id that is not affected by that merge? I don't know enough of your reducer logic. I was assuming the id is enough for your reducer to delete the item.

Comment: In state there is an object called `updates` that looks like this: `{1:{{field:'field value'}}` where 1 is the id of the object and "field value" is the value the user typed. In mapStateToProps the item passed by the list is merged with this if exist where user input will overwrite (see update at the end of the question). Example is [here](https://github.com/amsterdamharu/data-list/blob/master/example/client/src/containers/TaskItem/selectors.js)

Comment: @HMR I see but does your reducer actually require the information added by the merge or would the id be enough?

Comment: The selector needs to merge this. The data of items is stored in `state.items.data` user edits are stored in `state.list.edit[item.id]` The Item container has to merge those. I am merging it [here](https://github.com/amsterdamharu/data-list/blob/master/example/client/src/containers/TaskItem/selectors.js#L17-L37)

Comment: @HRM I see why you want to merge those. But as far as I can see in your reducer [here](https://github.com/amsterdamharu/data-list/blob/ac51dcc59b92c46fc40b7cb24aecbcc57667987b/List/reducer.js#L55) you only need the `id` of that item to reduce the action `requestDelete`. This is already in the `ownProps`  and unaffected by your merge. So I can't see why this wouldn't work.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/196377/discussion-between-hmr-and-trixn).